# python function wrapping not working

Tags: python, function, overriding

I got example on https://www.youtube.com for function wrapping ,but it throw exception.

```
def addOne(myfunc):

    def addOneInside(myfunc):       
        return myfunc()+1

    return addOneInside

def oldFunc():

    return 3

oldFunc=addOne(oldFunc)

print oldFunc()
```

error is :

> TypeError: addOneInside() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

can any body explain what is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addOneInside` does not need an argument. `myfunc` will be accessible via context.

Change it to

```
def addOne(myfunc):
    def addOneInside():       
        return myfunc()+1
    return addOneInside
```

Comment: A more general solution is to have the wrapper function take any arguments with `def addOneInside(*args, **kwargs)` and pass them on with `return myfunc(*args, **kwargs) + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

The terms here are a little odd - this isn't strictly function overriding, it's function *wrapping*. I think what you want is a decorator. @bytesized is correct syntax-wise, but there's more to be learned about what you're attempting. Here's a great write up that might help (walks through closures, local functions and works up to decorators): http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/